# I can't find the files I uploaded to Google Drive

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to upload a file to `Google Drive` using `Google Drive REST API v3`. After the upload process is completed, it returns a `status code of 200` (successful). But I can't find the files in my `Google Drive`. Please tell me what am I doing wrong? I will really appreciate if you provide a proper illustration or better still code snippet while helping me with this problem of mine. I am really anticipating your answers.
I have tried following the documentation but I am still getting the same error. I have searched everywhere online and stackoverflow, but none seems to provide the solution to my problem.
here is the code

```
 private val AUTHORIZATION_PARAM = "Authorization"
    private val BEARER_VAL = "Bearer "
    private val CONTENT_TYPE_PARAM = "Content-Type: "
    private val LINE_FEED = "\r\n"
    private val APP_FOLDER_ID = "appDataFolder"



    fun connectAndStartOperation() {
        if (mAuthCode == null) {
            signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
                .requestIdToken(resources.getString(R.string.gdrive_clientId))
                .requestServerAuthCode(resources.getString(R.string.gdrive_clientId))
                .build()

            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions!!)


            startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient?.signInIntent, CLOUD_STORAGE)


            Log.i("mAuthCode", "false")
        } else {
            Log.i("mAuthCode", "true")
            writeDbToDrive()
            mNextGoogleApiOperation = INVALID;
        }
    }


    fun disconnect() {
        mGoogleSignInClient?.signOut()
        mActivity = null
        mNextGoogleApiOperation = INVALID
        mAuthCode = null
        mAccessToken = null
        mTokenExpired = 0
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        disconnect()
        super.onDestroy()

    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == CLOUD_STORAGE) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this)
                .addOnFailureListener(this)


        }
    }

    override fun onSuccess(googleSignInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount?) {


        Log.i("mAuthCode", "Success")
        val scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

        idTokenString = googleSignInAccount?.idToken
        mAuthCode = googleSignInAccount?.serverAuthCode
        mGoogleSignInAccount = googleSignInAccount

        doAsync {
            try {
                mAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this@SettingsActivity, mGoogleSignInAccount?.account, scope)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.i("Error AccessToken", "${e.message}")

                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            uiThread {
                Log.i("AccessTokenMy", "$mAccessToken")
            }
        }


    }


    override fun onFailure(p0: java.lang.Exception) {
        Log.i("mAuthCode", "Failed")

        p0.printStackTrace()
    }


    private fun writeDbToDrive() {
        var conn: HttpURLConnection? = null
        var os: OutputStream? = null


        val accessToken = requestAccessToken(mGoogleSignInAccount!!)

        if (accessToken == null)
            return



        try {
            val boundary = "pb" + System.currentTimeMillis()
            val url = URL("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
            conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            conn.requestMethod = "POST"
            conn.useCaches = false
            conn.doOutput = true
            conn.doInput = true
            conn.connectTimeout = 5000
            conn.setRequestProperty(AUTHORIZATION_PARAM, BEARER_VAL + accessToken!!)
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=$boundary")

            Log.i("Action", "Parameter set for server")

            /////// Prepare data
            //val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            // Prepare file metadata (Change your backup file name here)
            val b = StringBuilder()
            b.append('{')
                .append("\"name\":\"").append(exportedFileName).append('\"')
                .append(',')
                .append("\"mimeType\":").append("\"text\\/csv\"")
                .append(',') //"\"application\\/vnd.google-apps.unknown\""
                .append("\"parents\":").append("[\"").append(APP_FOLDER_ID).append("\"]")
                .append('}')
            val metadata = b.toString()
            val data = readFile(File(filePath))

            /////// Calculate body length
            var bodyLength = 0
            // MetaData part
            b.setLength(0)
            b.append("--").append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append(CONTENT_TYPE_PARAM).append("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append(metadata).append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append("--").append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append(CONTENT_TYPE_PARAM).append("text/csv").append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append(LINE_FEED)
            val beforeFilePart = b.toString().toByteArray(charset("UTF_8"))
            bodyLength += beforeFilePart.size

            bodyLength += data.size // File

            b.setLength(0)
            b.append(LINE_FEED)
            b.append("--").append(boundary).append("--")
            val afterFilePart = b.toString().toByteArray(charset("UTF_8"))
            bodyLength += afterFilePart.size

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", bodyLength.toString())
            //if (BuildConfig.DEBUG_MODE) DebugHelper.log("LENGTH", bodyLength)

            /////// Write to socket
            os = conn.outputStream

            try {
                os!!.write(beforeFilePart)
                os!!.write(data)
                os!!.write(afterFilePart)
                os!!.flush()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


            val msg = conn.responseMessage
            val code = conn.responseCode


            if (code == 200) {
                Log.i("writeDbToDrive", "Exported Successfully: $code $msg")

            } else {
                Log.i("writeDbToDrive", "Error: $code $msg")

            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.i("writeDbToDrive", e.message!!)
        } finally {
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os!!.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                }

            }
            conn?.disconnect()
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun readFile(file: File): ByteArray {
        val f = RandomAccessFile(file, "r")
        try {
            val longlength = f.length()
            val length = longlength.toInt()
            if (length.toLong() != longlength)
                throw IOException("File size >= 10 Mb")

            val data = ByteArray(length)
            f.readFully(data)
            return data
        } finally {
            f.close()
        }
    }

    private fun requestAccessToken(mGoogleSignInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount): String? {

        val scope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"



        doAsync {
            try {
                mAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this@SettingsActivity, mGoogleSignInAccount?.account, scope)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.i("Error AccessToken", "${e.message}")

                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            uiThread {
                Log.i("AccessTokenMy", "$mAccessToken")
            }

        }

        return mAccessToken
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through this [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) Documentation, I have finally fixed the problem. Unknown to me is that the files where being saved in the `AppData` folder created by my app. The `AppData` folder is hidden which can only be accessible by and through my app. For me to be able to save the file to `My Drive` folder, I removed the part of the metadata

```
          ` .append(',') 
            .append("\"parents\":").append("[\"").append(APP_FOLDER_ID).append("\"]")`
```

So the metadata part is now like this

```
 val b = StringBuilder()
        b.append('{')
            .append("\"name\":\"").append(exportedFileName).append('\"')
            .append(',')
            .append("\"mimeType\":").append("\"text\\/csv\"")
            .append('}')
        val metadata = b.toString()
```

Every other thing remains the same

Comment: Hi @RashEngine, I'm doing almost the same thing and it works for me on the web but not on mobile. Please check this [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@nwaughachukwuma/react-native-to-google-drive-upload) to get an idea

On mobile, I get a 200 and the file id but I cannot see the uploaded file